# jQuery: about the output of serialize()

Tags: jquery

I'm getting this output after serializing a form using `serialize()`.

```
cambio_estado_factura%5Bestado%5D=1
```

As the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) says, I expected something in this format:

```
a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5
```

This is the form I'm serializing:

```
<form id="cambio_estado" action="">
    <div class="fld ">
        <label for="cambio_estado_factura_estado">Estado</label>
        <ul class="radio_list">
            <li>
                <input name="cambio_estado_factura[estado]" type="radio" value="1" id="cambio_estado_factura_estado_1">
                <label for="cambio_estado_factura_estado_1">Recibida</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input name="cambio_estado_factura[estado]" type="radio" value="2" id="cambio_estado_factura_estado_2">
                <label for="cambio_estado_factura_estado_2">Registrada</label>
            </li>
        </div>
    <input id="cambio_estado" type="submit" value="Cambiar">
</form>
```

And this is the jquery code:

```
$('form#cambio_estado').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert();
    console.log($('form#cambio_estado'));
    var datos_formulario = $('form#cambio_estado').serialize();
    console.log(datos_formulario);
    $.post($("section#consultarFactura").data("url-cambio-estado"),
        {"cambio_estado_factura": datos_formulario }
    );

});
```

Any idea?

jQuery 1.6.1

Comment: How are you calling serialize()? Do you call it on the form?

Comment: @Sjoerd I add the jquery code. It is between the script tags and below the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually is the correct behavior for `serialize()`.

Your issue is that the name in the form is `cambio_estado_factura[estado]`. This would actually translate to `cambio_estado_factura%5Bestado%5D`, which is the escaped name of the element. `Serialize()` will take the name you use for each element on the form. If you want to have a different name appear on the resulting query string, use the appropriate names on the form itself.

An example - this form will return `a=1&a=2` on calling `serialize()` on it.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="a" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="b" value="2" />
</form>
```

EDIT:

Referring to your comments, this is my example of `parse_str`:

```
parse_str('cambio_estado_factura%5Bestado%5D=1', $arr);
var_dump($arr);
echo $arr["cambio_estado_factura"]["estado"] == 1 ? "Value set" : "Value not set";
```

This returns:

```
array
 'cambio_estado_factura' => 
    array
      'estado' => string '1' (length=1)

Value set
```

Which means that you assume your array is single-level while in fact it is multi-level.

Comment: But Im trying to deserialize that string using parse_php() in my php server code, and I'm getting an empty array..I'm using parse_php('cambio_estado_factura%5Bestado%5D=1', $data)

Comment: I 'm not that up to date with PHP, but I think `parse_php` it's a non-standard function. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The string has been encoded.

```
%20 is space
%5B is '['
and %5D is ']'
```

Since you have given `cambio_estado_factura[5Bestado]` as an array, the final output it passes is only one parameter:

```
cambio_estado_factura[5Bestado] = 1
```

This is same as [**URL Encoding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and it is the safe way of transmitting content to URLs. This is the expected way too.

Answer (score 0):

Its taking the `name` of the input, which is `name="cambio_estado_factura[estado]"` also, since the two input controls share the same name, the form will submit just one.

> The name is used when sending data in a form submission. Different controls respond differently. For example, you may have several radio buttons with different ids, but the same name. When submitted, there is just the one value in the response.

So be careful to have unique names in the form.